# Parsing the nested array of objects in JSON using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, parsing

I am new to Angular.js. Here i am developing a shopping cart where i have to display image, name and cost of a product. I have multiple tenants and each tenant have array listOfBinaries  which contains listOfMerchandise. Myproblem is i have to show name from tenants, image from listOfBinary and cost from listOfMerchandise.  I parsed the JSON as shown below but while running i am getting empty page.  Can any one please help me. 
Here is my JSON which i got after making an AJAX call to the REST URL:

```
{
"_links": {
    "search": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/search"
    }
},
"_embedded": {
    "tenants": [
        {
            "name": "tenant1",
            "domainName": "gaming.com",
            "description": "sasasa",
            "listOfBinary": [
                {
                    "imageURL": "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02602/premier-league_2602603b.jpg",
                    "username": "Sumanth",
                    "description": "imagSky Sports offer free live Premier League action on o Sky Sports offer free live Premier League action on opening weekend of season as battle witpening weekend of season as battle wite1",
                    "listOfMerchandise": [
                        {
                            "rate": 100,
                            "type": "item1",
                            "shortDescription": "test1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "imageURL": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
                    "username": "as",
                    "description": "Sky Sports offer free live Premier League action on opening weekend of season as battle wit Sky Sports offer free live Premier League action on opening weekend of season as battle wit",
                    "listOfMerchandise": [
                        {
                            "rate": 200,
                            "type": "item2",
                            "shortDescription": "test2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "merchandise": null,
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/2"
                },
                "listOfCustomerPackage": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/2/listOfCustomerPackage"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "tenant2",
            "domainName": "cric.io",
            "listOfBinary": [
                {
                    "imageURL": "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02602/premier-league_2602603b.jpg",
                    "username": "Sumanth",
                    "description": "Sky Sports offer free live Premier League action on opening weekend of season as battle wit Sky Sports offer free live Premier League action on opening weekend of season as battle wit",
                    "listOfMerchandise": [
                        {
                            "rate": 500,
                            "type": "item5",
                            "shortDescription": "test5"
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "imageURL": "www.test.com",
                    "username": "sumanth",
                    "description": "sample",
                    "listOfMerchandise": [
                        {
                            "rate": 2323,
                            "type": "type7",
                            "shortDescription": "test"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "merchandise": null,
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/9"
                },
                "listOfCustomerPackage": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/9/listOfCustomerPackage"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "tenant5",
            "domainName": "test.co",
            "description": "test 123 ",
            "listOfBinary": [],
            "binary": {
                "fileLocation": "www.test.com",
                "username": "sumanth",
                "description": "sample",
                "listOfMerchandise": [
                    {
                        "rate": 2323,
                        "type": "trt",
                        "shortDescription": "rtrtrt"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

My directives.js file: I am getting above JSON when i make this Ajax call

```
 myAppDirectives.
  controller('items_display', function ($scope,$http) {
 $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/' }).success(function (data) {
 $scope.carts=data; 
 }).
 error(function (data) {
     alert("error" + data);
     console.log(data);
 });
 });
```

My HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 < html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div  ng-controller="items_display">
    <div  ng-repeat="item in carts._embedded.tenants">
    <div type="text" class="item_name" value={{item.name}}  > 
    <div  ng-repeat="item in carts._embedded.tenants.listOfBinary">
     <img  class="shop_img" ng-src="{{item.fileLocation}}"  ng-style="{'width':'100px', 'height':'100px'}" /> 
     <div  ng-repeat="item in carts._embedded.tenants.listOfBinary.listOfMerchandise">
      <div type="text" class="item_cost" value={{item.rate}}  > 
    </div>  
      </br>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone please help to to display the product details on html page using Angular.js.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you have any console errors?

Comment: @maurycy thanks for replay.  no console errors.

Comment: @maurycy is my code is correct which i wrote in my HTML page to parse JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is all messed up, check the plunker I've made with your data and markup

http://plnkr.co/edit/jGCm6nO9S4hlNxLCyrSy?p=preview

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="items_display">
      <div ng-repeat="tenant in carts._embedded.tenants">
        <div type="text" class="item_name">{{tenant.name}}
          <div ng-repeat="binary in tenant.listOfBinary">
            <img class="shop_img" ng-src="{{binary.fileLocation}}" ng-style="{'width':'100px', 'height':'100px'}" />
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in binary.listOfMerchandise[0]">
              <div type="text" class="item_cost">{{key}}: {{value}}
              </div>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.